# add support for AMD graphics card

Tags: pantheon-files, graphic-drivers, pantheon, elementary-website, amd

i am using hp notebook and i switched from windows to elementary OS and don't find support for AMD graphics card please give driver update
hope you will work on my request

Comment: There's already support for amd cards. If you need help configuring your laptop, open a terminal and update your question with the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to know more information about your system, but I will tell you what worked in my case:

download the driver from the official website of amd. After that unzip and edit the files **amdgpu-install** and **amdgpu-pro-install**.
In line 90 change ubuntu by elementary and save the change.

If you do not do that, it will say OS not supported.

Depending on the version of the driver you will also need to edit the system file **/ etc / os-release** on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "0.4" to VERSION_ID = "16.04" if you are using Eos loki (open "files" with administrator privileges for to be able to make the change).

After that open the folder where the driver is with the terminal and put there:

./amdgpu-pro-install -y

(this installs Base kernel, Accelerated graphics, Multimedia table, Pro OpenGL, Pro Vulkan, Pro OpenCL).

After installing everything correctly edit the system file / etc / os-release again, on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "16.04" to VERSION_ID = "0.4" to leave that file as it was before.

Sorry bad english.